# Divide counts from two different sql tables without a join

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Hey I have scoured the forum for something similar to this, but can't quite find anything. I am trying to get a conversion percentage, so a count from the bottom of funnel divided by a count from top of funnel. These two counts live on two separate tables in my database that are not joinable.

I wrote this code but keep getting 0 when I know it should not be 0

```
SELECT
(((
SELECT COUNT(p.id)
FROM partner_subscriptions AS p)
/
(
SELECT COUNT(a.id)
FROM salesforce_leads AS a)) * 100) as percentage
```

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL and SQL Server are very different.  I'm removing those tags and replacing them with sql.  Feel free to add the one database you are using.

Comment: MYSQL, see my new comment also please!

Comment: Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: I can set up SQL Fiddle, think that will help me solve my next problem here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810293/divide-counts-from-different-tables-without-a-join-based-upon-date-groupings)

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server does integer division (MySQL does not).  You can simply fix the problem by getting a real number rather than an integer

```
SELECT ((SELECT 1.0*COUNT(p.id) FROM partner_subscriptions p) /
        (SELECT COUNT(sl.id) FROM salesforce_leads sl) * 100)
       ) as percentage
```

I'm also a big fan of formatting code so it is readable.

EDIT:

In MySQL you would only get zero when

```
SELECT COUNT(p.id)
FROM partner_subscriptions p
```

returns 0.  Or, if you have some mistake reading the returned value from the query.

Comment: see new post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810293/divide-counts-from-different-tables-without-a-join-based-upon-date-groupings)

Answer (score 2):

You do Integer Division. It means that 4 / 10 = 0. You need to cast one number to float/decimal or multiply by 1.0 to get 1.0 * 4 / 10 = 0.4

```
SELECT (( 1.0 *
       (SELECT COUNT(p.id)
        FROM partner_subscriptions AS p) /
       (SELECT COUNT(a.id)
        FROM salesforce_leads AS a) ) * 100) AS percentage
```

Comment: see new post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810293/divide-counts-from-different-tables-without-a-join-based-upon-date-groupings)